# Troubles with add http headers php

Tags: php, apache

Ok, I creating blog, just for learn php. And when I try redirect page after Sign in or sign up, I use header("Location: /") for example, for redirect to home page of blog. And it's work only when I use var_dump()... This my code, help pls

This method from Mediator, which send response for user and here headers added.

```
 /**
 * @param ResponseInterface $response
 */
public function sendResponse(ResponseInterface $response)
{
    $response->addHeaders();
    var_dump($response->getHeaders());
    http_response_code($response->getStatusCode());
    if ($response->getStatusCode() !== 200) {

        die($response->getContent());
    }
    echo $response->getContent();
}
```

This method from controller with sign up

```
/**
 * @return ResponseInterface
 * @throws \ReflectionException
 * @throws \core\FileNotFoundException
 */
public function signInAction()
{
    $authForm = $this->createAuthForm();

    if ($authForm->load()) {
        if ($authForm->isValid() && $authForm->login()) {
            return new SuccessResponse('Welcome!',[ '0' => 'Location: /',]);
        }
        ErrorsCheckHelper::setError('Wrong login or password');
        return $this->renderLogin();
    }

    return $this->renderLogin();
}
```

And this is my class for response which I used in this case

```
namespace response;
class SuccessResponse implements ResponseInterface{
/** @var int */
protected $statusCode = 200;
/** @var string */
protected $content;

/** @var array */
protected $headers;

/**
 * SuccessResponse constructor.
 * @param $headers
 * @param $content
 */
public function __construct(string $content, array $headers = array())
{
    $this->headers = $headers;
    $this->content = $content;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getHeaders(): array
{
    return $this->headers;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getContent(): string
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * @param string $content
 */
public function setContent(string $content): void
{
    $this->content = $content;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getStatusCode(): int
{
    return $this->statusCode;
}


/**
 * @param array $headers
 */
public function setHeaders(array $headers)
{
    array_merge($this->headers, [$headers]);
}

public function addHeaders()
{
    if (!empty($this->headers)) {
        foreach ($this->headers as $header) {
            header($header);
        }
    }
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: First thing you need to do is make sure you can see any errors if they occur. In your `php.ini` config file, make sure you have `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On`. You may need to restart Apache if you make changes to this file

Answer (score 1):

The values of the headers that you want to set should be indexed by their name, not by a numeric value or other string, so where you had this:

```
      return new SuccessResponse('Welcome!',[ '0' => 'Location: /',]);
```

try using:

```
      return new SuccessResponse('Welcome!',[ 'Location: /']);
```

Comment: I try it, and after this, redirect stop working even with var_dump()T.T

Comment: use `return new SuccessResponse('Welcome!',[ 'Location: /']);`

Comment: Yeah, you might need to play around with the way you create the array a little bit to find the right pattern, @Cemal may have the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, just whaaaaat.....
I fix code like this and it's start work

```
/**
 * @param ResponseInterface $response
 */
public function sendResponse(ResponseInterface $response)
{
    http_response_code($response->getStatusCode());
    if ($response->getStatusCode() !== 200) {
        $response->addHeaders();
        die($response->getContent());
    }
    $response->addHeaders();
    echo $response->getContent();
}
```